# Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

Tags: java

While running java program getting following error in eclipse

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7
```

Although I am using java 1.7.25 and all eclipse settings are in place but not sure why getting this error

**SOLUTION.**

Problem solved by updating project in eclipse using maven.

Comment: Check the compiler compliance level and make sure it's set to Java 7. Just having JDK 7 is not enough, you should let eclipse know how to use it.

Comment: In eclipse window->preferences->java->Compiler Compiler compliance level settings are set to 1.7

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Despite of the fact that you are using Java 1.7 you can compile source code as if you had compiler from Java 1.6 (this can be useful for example for cross-compilation).
As [Shivam Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813102/shivam-tiwari) said in Eclipse you can change it in window->preferences->java->Compiler Compiler

If you are using Maven you should add the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: is there no way for a solution if you aren't using maven?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse. Go to Project->Properties->Click on Java Compiler and change Compiler compliance level to 1.8 or above.
It works for me many times.

Answer (score 0):

Maven update with 'Force snapshot release' did the trick. pom.xml doesn't need to be changed.